# PHP Sessions lost on url redirect

Tags: php, session, box-api

I'm using PHP SDK with Box API. I've been desperately trying to send variables to be used initially for a search in Box. I've found that once the page is redirected by Box API after login the session variables (or any variables at all that have been sent or assigned before authentication) are lost. I've had session_start() at the beginning of each page I've tried.

Any idea on how I can keep my variables in session?

Answer (score 0):

I don't precisely know the answer to your question, but you might consider saving the session info in the authorization URL's [state](http://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2-authorize) variable.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, PHP SDK does not yet have a version 2 of the API. I forgot to mention that I'm still working under v1.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the PHP SDK for v2

Have a look [here](http://www.ulhas.net/GitHub/BoxPHPAPI/)
Download: [BoxPHPAPI](https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI)